# How to avoid conflict FKs with the main table insert Linq to sql?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq-to-sql

I wrote the following code to insert into the db,for information about a staff.

The problem I face for multiple FK of tables (languages , certificates and DoctorType) to the main table (staff).

I'm having the following exception

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_certificates_staff". The conflict occurred in database
>   "D:\UNI\CLINIK.MDF", table "dbo.staff", column 'id'

**My code :**

```
public bool AddnewStaff(staff s , List<language> ln, List<certificate> cer, DoctorType dt)
   {
       using (DataClasses1DataContext ex = new DataClasses1DataContext())
       {
           try
           {
                // First insert Tables(lalanguage ,certificate , DoctorType ) that has FK to         staff table
                IEnumerable<language> lang = getAllLanguages(ln);
                IEnumerable<certificate> certificat = getAllCer(cer);
                ex.languages.InsertAllOnSubmit(lang); // insert list of languages
                ex.certificates.InsertAllOnSubmit(certificat); //insert list of certificates
                ex.DoctorTypes.InsertOnSubmit(dt);
                ex.SubmitChanges();

               //Now that those FKs are filled, we can insert the main entry with those FK values
               // now insert table staff 
                staff sa = new staff();
                sa = s;
                sa.certificates.Add((certificate)certificat);
                sa.languages.Add((language)lang);
                sa.DoctorTypes.Add(dt);
                ex.staffs.InsertOnSubmit(sa);
                ex.SubmitChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<language> getAllLanguages(List<language> ln)
    {
        var lang = (IEnumerable<language>)ln;
        return lang;
    }

    public IEnumerable<certificate> getAllCer(List<certificate> cer)
    {
        // convert from list of certificate to IEnumerable<certificate> to use InsertAllOnSubmit method to insert into DB
        var c = (IEnumerable<certificate>)cer;
        return c;
    }
}
```

Any idea about what to do ?

Comment: What are the two functions at the end good for? You should delete them. A `List<>` already implements `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: Why is existing Staff passed to a method called Add **New** Staff and then used?

Comment: because when I write the following i have another error     ex.languages.InsertAllOnSubmit(ln); // insert list of languages
                    ex.certificates.InsertAllOnSubmit(cer); //insert list of certificates
                    ex.DoctorTypes.InsertOnSubmit(dt);
                    ex.SubmitChanges();        staff sa = new staff();
                    sa = s;
                    sa.certificates.Add(cer);
                    sa.languages.Add(ln);   // says invalid arguments

Comment: You should really work out basic C# before you try databases. This has nothing to do with databases. The `.Add()` method takes a single argument while you are passing a whole list. Check if the collections have an `.AddRange()` method or manually write a foreach loop to insert each list element using `.Add()`.

Comment: I wrote for each like you said and I;m still having the same exception @nvoigt

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find my crystal ball. For those poor fellows who don't own a magic "view other peoples code through the internet" crystal ball, could you post your new code?